# I can't make 100x120 thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, scale, thumbnails

I need to make three thumbnails for one Wordpress template:

- 678x301 px
- 271x120 px
- 100x120 px

So I have put these on functions.php:

```
<?php add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 271, 120, true );
add_image_size( 'featured', 678, 301, true );
add_image_size( 'sieme', 100, 120, true );
?>
```

But unfortunately, the third one doesn't work. When I use this, it doesn't link to foo_100x120.jpg (which exists, I've checked manually), but to foo.jpg and set width and height by HTML. Here is the screen with single post view, where I've put three thumbnails for the test. HTML is below, in Firebug:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCTM8.png

Here is the part of single.php:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail( 'featured' );
    the_post_thumbnail( 'index-thumb' );
    the_post_thumbnail( 'sieme' );
    } 
?>
```

I don't know, why it happens.

Comment: Did you have those 3 sizes when you uploaded the image? I think I read the thumbs are generated when you upload, so if you didn't have the last size then, you would not get that size.

Answer (score 0):

If the images already exist, you'll need to use the [Regenerate Thumbnails Plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). After you've ran it once any uploaded images should be cropped as expected.